# Height issue when combining jQuery dialog and tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you use jQuery `dialog()` you get a perfectly centered popup on your screen. When I introduce `tabs()` inside the dialog, the vertical distance between the top of the box and the top of the browser window is less than that of the bottom of the popup to bottom of browser.

I don't want to add a height variable to `dialog()` because I want it to scale automatically according to the content.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    width: 409,
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Popup">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#fragment-1">Tab 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#fragment-2">Tab 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">
      lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
      lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-2">
      lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
      lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
      ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you encountering is, since `tabs` are being initialized *after* the `dialog`, some of the tabs css rules are overriding css rules for dialog and moving it up the display.

The simplest way to fix this is to move both your dialog and tabs initialization into the same document ready call and just initialize tabs *before* your dialog:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        width: 409,
    });
});
```

The more complicated way to fix this would be to determine what css rules are in conflict and rectify them. Or, you could simply move the dialog to the center of the screen after the tabs initialization if you can't change the order.